# How to get the default price of the product with different prices from different date periods from the period closest to today?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms, eloquent-relationship, octobercms-backend

[my sqlfiddle eample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1249d9/39)

Hello there,

according to the above sqlfiddle example;

I have a table A where the products are listed and a table B with different prices for different periods associated with these products.

Here I show these prices according to the date the user has chosen. There is no problem.

However, if the user has not selected a date, I cannot show the price of the period closest to today by default.

In the example I gave, the sql query does this successfully, but I cannot write it successfully in the form of laravel query. Or as an Eloquent orm query

How can I do that?

```
$query->select(['tableA.*', 'tableB.start_date', 'tableB.end_date', 'tableB.price'])
                            ->join('tableB', function($join) {
                            $join->on('tableA.id', '=', 'tableB.pro_id');
                            })->where(function($sq) use ($postFrom) {
                                $sq->when($postFrom[0]=='0', function ($syq) {
                                    $syq->whereRaw('DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(tableB.end_date)');
                                }, function ($stq) use ($postFrom) {
                                    $stq->whereDate('tableB.start_date', '<=', $postFrom[0])
                                       ->whereDate('tableB.end_date', '>=', $postFrom[0]);
                                });
                            })->orWhere(function($ssq) use ($postTo) {
                                $ssq->whereDate('tableB.start_date', '<=', $postTo[0])
                                    ->whereDate('tableB.end_date', '>=', $postTo[0]);
                    })->groupBy('tableA.id')->orderBy('tableB.price', $sortDirection);
```

note1: $postFrom and $postTo are the start and end dates from the user. If the user did not submit a date, $postFrom is displayed as 0.

note2: I show the default price when the $postFrom[0] == '0' condition is met.

note3: The '2021-03-07' value in the sqlfiddle example is used for example instead of the dynamic present value.

note4: According to this query, it takes the price value of the first period as default. But that's not what I want.

note5: I can't use 'joinSub' because Laravel version is 5.5.

note6:In the example I want to convert to Laravel Query form, the sql query that works without any problems:

```
select `tableA`.*, `tableB`.`start_date`, `tableB`.`end_date`, `tableB`.`price`  
from `tableA` 
right join( 
  SELECT id, start_date, end_date, pro_id, price, DATEDIFF(`tableB`.`end_date`, '2021-03-07') diff 
  FROM `tableB` GROUP BY id order by diff asc 
) `tableB` on `tableA`.`id` = `tableB`.`pro_id` where (date(`end_date`) >= '2021-03-07') 
  group by `tableA`.`id` order by `price` desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an equivalent query of your query. I haven't executed.

**If Laravel Version is greater then 5.5**

```
$query1 = DB::table('tableB')
          ->selectRaw("id, start_date, end_date, pro_id, price, DATEDIFF(end_date, '2021-03-07') AS diff")
         ->groupBy('id')->orderBy('diff','ASC');
    
TableA::select('tableA.*', 'tableB.start_date', 'tableB.end_date', 'tableB.price')
         ->joinSub($query1, 'tableB', function ($join)
        {
              $join->on('tableA.id', '=', 'tableB.pro_id');
        })
        ->whereDate('tableB.end_date','>=','2021-03-07')
        ->groupBy('tableA.id')->orderBy('price','DESC')->get();
```

**For Laravel 5.5**

```
TableA::select('tableA.*', 'tableB.start_date', 'tableB.end_date', 'tableB.price')
         ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT id, start_date, end_date, pro_id, price, 
         DATEDIFF(`tableB`.`end_date`, '2021-03-07') diff 
         FROM `tableB` GROUP BY id order by diff asc) table2 "), function ($join)
        {
              $join->on('tableA.id', '=', 'table2.pro_id');
        })
        ->whereDate('table2.end_date','>=','2021-03-07')
        ->groupBy('tableA.id')->orderBy('price','DESC')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I apologize for not mentioning the laravel version. I am adding it as a note right now. I can't use 'joinSub' because Laravel version is 5.5.

Comment: in that case use `DB::raw`

Comment: I tested with different variations yes it works! Amazing, I've tried so many things like this for days. :)  Now there is only one question left. How can we send the '2021-03-07' part dynamically in DB::raw? Should send your date today

Comment: '2021-03-07' will be current date or can be any date?

Comment: You can pass it in a variable. $date = '2021-0307'